# Ubuntu upstream connection issue

Tags: networking, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and recently my device has been randomly unable to access the outside internet (WiFi).

**System Configuration:** I have checked DNSs, Interface configuration, routing tables and any other network related settings on my machine, and everything seems normal, and I have not recently changed anything which could impact networking from my machine.

**Problem Scope:** I am able to connect to other devices on my LAN, and the issue is isolated to my Ubuntu machine, meaning that It is not likely a router configuration issue. Additionally: whilst I initially thought this to be an Application layer issue concerning the Firefox browser, I am also unable to Ping Google, or any other address outside my LAN.

**Rebooting:** I have been able to temporarily solve this problem by rebooting, however after a few hours, the problem resurfaces and I'm no longer to connect to the outside world.

**IPS/IDS:** I have an Intrusion Detection/Prevention system installed, which is capable of proactively blocking IP addresses which reach a certain threshold of potentially malicious traffic. Although false-positives are relatively likely, logging and service stats reveal no blocked addresses. I have also checked my firewall to ensure that no DNSs or Google servers are being blocked.

**System Updates:** I have updated all packages on the system completely in the hope that the problem may be solved, however the problem persists.

Unless there is some secret that I am in the dark about, none of the conventional networking problem-solving techniques seem to be working, which is why I am resorting to the Stack Exchange for help.

Also considering how common this type of question likely is, I readily anticipate the down-votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it by adding Google DNS `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `resolv.conf` file located in `/etc/`. Not sure why I am encountering this DNS issue, I suspect the fault lies with my ISP, which is odd since the error is still isolated to this particular machine.